# Plot Axes for Multiple Surfaces in the same Mayavi figure?

Tags: mayavi

I want to plot multiple surfaces in the same plot, and have the axes extend over all surfaces.

```
import numpy as np
# Create data with x and y random in the [-2, 2] segment, and z a
# Gaussian function of x and y.
np.random.seed(12345)
x = 4 * (np.random.random(500) - 0.5)
y = 4 * (np.random.random(500) - 0.5)
def f(x, y):
    return np.exp(-(x ** 2 + y ** 2))
z = f(x, y)
from mayavi import mlab
myfig = mlab.figure(1, fgcolor=(0, 0, 0), bgcolor=(1, 1, 1))
for i in range(3):
  z = z + 1
  # Visualize the points
  pts = mlab.points3d(x, y, z, z,figure=myfig, scale_mode='none', scale_factor=0.2)
  # Create and visualize the mesh
  mesh = mlab.pipeline.delaunay2d(pts,figure=myfig)
  surf = mlab.pipeline.surface(mesh,figure=myfig)
  pts.remove()
mlab.axes(figure=myfig)
mlab.show()
```

The code above is my attempt to include my axes over all surfaces, but it fails to do so.

[image]

The plot above is the result of my code which only extends the axes over the last surface. I thought I could fix this my forcing all mlab functions to specify the figure to plot to, but that failed to extend axes over all surfaces.

Comment: By using the "pipelines" of mayavi, you define objects (here, the mesh) that have no bounds and you cannot use "fancy" features such as automatic axes. I suggest that you generate the data for your mesh separately and use the mayavi `mlab.surf` function instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the extent of the objects (here only z is unknown, you said x and y are in (-2, 2)), and pass it as the `ranges` argument to `mlab.axes()`:

`mlab.axes(figure=myfig, ranges=[-2, 2, -2, 2, z.min(), z.max()])`